# MySQL stored procedure to find the closest matching call rate for a phone call

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, stored-procedures, string-matching

## I've got two phone numbers, an a-party and b-party which I want to find the closest matching call rate for.

There is a table of call rates containing various a-party and b-party numbers and rates per min.

When looking up a call rate, first the most specific match in the a-party is found. If a b-party match is found, the rate from the most specific b-party match is used.
If a b-party match is not found for the a-party, the next most specific a-party match is looked at to see if it has a b-party match. If no match is found, a separate message must be returned.

```
i.e 
call_rates
a-party     b-party    rate_per_min
6495631234  619234     0.10
6495631     6192       0.12
649         61923      0.09
649         61         0.16
```

For the above call rates, a call from:

`a-party: 6495631234` to `b-party: 619234567` would return the `rate_per_min: 0.10`

`a-party: 6495631111` to `b-party: 619234567` would return the `rate_per_min: 0.12`

`a-party: 6495631111` to `b-party: 611112345` would return the `rate_per_min: 0.16`

`a-party: 6495631111` to `b-party: 619234566` would return the `rate_per_min: 0.09`

This is how I've attempted to go about it so far. This is a very rough outline. I have limited experience in writing stored procedures.

I'm just looking for some advice about whether there is a better way to go about this. The call rate table will be very large, so I can imagine having a double for loop will be very inefficient.

Any feedback will be much appreciate.

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `get_rate`;
CREATE PROCEDURE `get_rate` (a VARCHAR(45), b VARCHAR(45), OUT rate VARCHAR(45))
get_r:BEGIN
    DECLARE i, j INT;
    DECLARE match_string, result, temp_string VARCHAR(255);

    SET j = LENGTH(b);
    SET i = LENGTH(a);

    WHILE i > 0 DO
        SET temp_string = SUBSTRING(a,0,i);
        SET result = (SELECT * FROM call_rate_overrides WHERE a_party LIKE CONCAT(temp_string, '%'));
        WHILE j > 0 DO
            SET temp_string = SUBSTRING(b,0,j);
            SET match_string = (SELECT * FROM call_rate_overrides WHERE b_party LIKE CONCAT(temp_string,'%'));
            IF ISNOTNULL(match_string) THEN
                SET rate = match_string;
                LEAVE get_r;
            END IF;  
            SET j = j - 1;
        END WHILE;
    
        SET i = i - 1;
    END WHILE;
END //
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up solving the problem this way:

```
SELECT     s.a_party, s.b_party, (
           SELECT  cr.rate_per_min
           FROM call_rate_overrides cr
           WHERE s.a_party LIKE CONCAT(cr.a_party, '%')
           AND s.b_party   LIKE CONCAT(cr.b_party,  '%')
           ORDER BY LENGTH(cr.a_party) + LENGTH(cr.b_party) DESC, cr.rate_per_min
           LIMIT 1
     ) as rate_per_min
FROM call_usages s
```

Where call usages are a table of a and b parties. It matches the longest database entry for the full length parties by ordering them based on the length of the match.

Comment: Sorry, this query returns `0.16` for all 4 matches. See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b402c/1 See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12720493/1432614 and http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b402c/13 for an answer that provides the result.

Comment: You're right. At the moment it's ordering the inner query results by ASC, so the shortest match i.e 0.16 is always at the top, so returned. I've updated the answer to order the inner query by DESC, now the correct rate is outputted. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Malcolm, your query now works great, and is much less complicated than mine. Great job! The only change you might make is to `ORDER BY (LENGTH(cr.a_party) * 10) + (LENGTH(cr.b_party) * 9) DESC`. This will give a higher weighing to the `a_party` then the `b_party`.

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
SELECT 
  s.a_party,
  s.b_party,
  cr.rate_per_min
FROM
    call_rate_overrides cr
INNER JOIN
    call_usages s ON 
        s.a_party LIKE CONCAT(cr.a_party, '%') AND
        s.b_party LIKE CONCAT(cr.b_party, '%')
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT 
    s.a_party,
    s.b_party,
    MAX(LENGTH(cr.a_party) + LENGTH(cr.b_party)) as len
  FROM
    call_rate_overrides cr
  INNER JOIN
    call_usages s ON 
      s.a_party LIKE CONCAT(cr.a_party, '%') AND
      s.b_party LIKE CONCAT(cr.b_party, '%')
  GROUP BY
    s.a_party,
    s.b_party
) d ON
    d.a_party = s.a_party AND
    d.b_party = s.b_party AND
    d.len = LENGTH(cr.a_party) + LENGTH(cr.b_party)
ORDER BY
  d.a_party,
  d.b_party
```

returns

```
a_party     b_party     rate_per_min
6495631111  611112345   0.16
6495631111  619234566   0.12
6495631111  619234567   0.12
6495631234  619234567   0.10
```

which matches all but one of the results in your question:

```
a-party: 6495631111 to b-party: 619234566 would return the rate_per_min: 0.09
```

If you look carefully, you'll see that the correct answer, is indeed 0.12.

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b402c/13 for a working example.

Comment: I wouldn't say this lends itself to understandability or good design, manually listing all those options for the case statement is horrible to create and worse to maintain or troubleshoot, also very error prone due to the human element.

Comment: You are indeed correct about the example call **a-party:** 6495631111 to **b-party:** 619234566 call rate being 0.12. Thank you for pointing this out.